# Como trazer resultado SQL agrupado por ano e dentro os meses

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho uma tabela assim:

```
data               |id
2017-02-01 00:00:00|1
2017-02-01 00:00:00|5
2017-04-01 00:00:00|2
2018-02-01 00:00:00|3
2018-04-01 00:00:00|4
```

Aí eu faço uma consulta com PHP no Mysql que me traz

```
SELECT id, data
FROM orders
GROUP BY data
```

e traz no php

```
foreach($results as $row){
echo date('m',$row->data).'<br/>';
}
```

o resultado acima fica:

```
02
04
02
04
```

Mas queria que ele trouxesse agrupado por ano tbm:

```
2017
02
04

2018
02
04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, sem saber o que está retornando fica bem difícil responder. Você pode tentar com esse código. Ele cria uma matriz para agrupar seus resultados em um array multidimensional.

```
foreach($results as $row){
    $mes = date('m',$row->data);
    $ano =  date('y',$row->data);
    $dia = date('d', $row->data);
    $intervals[$ano][$mes] = $dia;

}

foreach($intervals as $ano => $meses){
    echo $ano . "</br></br>";
    foreach($meses as $mes => $dia){
        echo $mes . "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: ele tá trazendo os resultados vazio, fiz um echo $mes e $ano, veio certinho, mas no intervals, veio vazio

Comment: na verdade, ele apare como resultado: ano

Comment: Bem testa esse novo (editado). caso dê errado você pode me mostrar qual função ou método você usa para obter `$results`

Comment: Perfeito! deu certinho, valeu!!!

Comment: As manipulações que o PHP tem com arrays são as ferramentas mais poderosas que a linguagem possuí. O programador que dominar bem essas manipulações terá uma produtividade acima da média.  ;)

Comment: vou dar uma estudada nisso, sou iniciante ainda, vlw!!

Comment: Recomento  PHP - Programando com orientação a objetos - Pablo Dall'Oglio. O primeiro capitulo traz uma abordagem prática às ferramentas de manipulação de valores.

Comment: só teve um problema na verdade,  se tiverem 2 meses do mesmo ano só aparece 1 mês, ex: datas 02/2018, 03/2018 e 02/2017, só aparece 02/2018 e 02/2017

Comment: Eu editei a resposta. Bem seria bom se você fornecesse um `var_dump($results)`

Comment: Show, agora deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro problema no seu código é que se a data for a mesma e a hora diferente, eles não será agrupados, então o ideal é você agrupar pelo ano e mês da data, o `select` ficaria assim:

```
SELECT id, data
FROM orders
GROUP BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data);
```

Já a impressão na tela ficaria assim:

```
$anoAnterior = '';
foreach($results as $row){
    $anoAtual = date('Y', $row->data)
    if (($anoAnterior != '') && ($anoAnterior != $anoAtual))
        echo "<br />";
    if ($anoAnterior != $anoAtual)
        echo $anoAtual.'<br />';
    echo date('m', $row->data).'<br/>';
}
```